# PyQGIS - QgsMapToolEmitPoint

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I would like to make use of Signal and Slot while using PyQgis along with PyQt4.

Despite spending some time trying out tutorials and some somewhat related post on gis.stackexchange I can't figure out a proper way of using the canvasClicked signal returned from the QgsMapToolEmitPoint Class ([API doc](http://qgis.org/api/2.0/classQgsMapToolEmitPoint.html#a60ce29ed6dbd8213ce3b34511873b0b5)).

Here after is where I'm at. I am building my application from the few tutorials man can find over the internet.

```
    self.clickPoint_action = QAction(
        QIcon(":/ourapp/zoomin_icon"),
        "Click Point",
        self)


    # create toolbar
    self.toolbar.addAction(self.clickPoint_action)

    # connect the tool
    self.clickPoint_action.triggered.connect(self.clickPoint)


    # create the map tool(s)
    self.tool_clickPoint = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.map_canvas)


def clickPoint(self):
    self.map_canvas.setMapTool(self.tool_clickPoint)
```

So, I understand how to set my map tool (and successfuly use other built-in and custom MapTool), but can't figure out where to go from there to get the corresponding QgsPoint emitted after a mouse click.

I have few experience on Python and just dive into Qt and PyGIS but already have some background mostly wth java.

thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the connect for the clicked signal:

```
 self.tool_clickPoint.canvasClicked.connect(self.clicked)


 def clicked(self, point, button):
    ....
```

Comment: That perfectly answers my question. Very clear. But I don't understand where that was described  in the API doc.