# Custom QGIS maptool to return current event

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, multithreading, qthread

This is what I am trying to do.
I designed an interface which can switch between selection mode and placement mode.

[image]

Selection mode activates the selection tool. Placement mode is what I am struggling atm. when the user selects "placement mode" It activates Custom Maptool which I designed. The maptool will ask the user to click on map canvas. And will wait until something is clicked or Esc button clicked.(I dont know how to force the code to wait for the result from click).
The maptool should be disabled after one click. and return the value of click point to the method which activates maptool.

here is my code for maptool which needs to return clicked point(QgsMapMouseEvent object). and deactivate itself after one click.

```
class EventHandler(QgsMapTool):

def __init__(self):
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    self.canvas = canvas
    QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
    self.setCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)
    #self.current_event=""#this  holdes an instance of current event
    self.button_clicked=""



def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
    """This method passes the instance of current event"""
    global current_event
    current_event=event
    self.canvas.unsetMapTool(EventHandler())
    Return event #here I want to return value




def keyPressEvent(self,event):
   print event
```

Here is the method which initiates CustomMapTool

```
def placement_mode(self):
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    result=canvas.setMapTool(EventHandler())
    #should wait here till user click on map canvas
    print result
```

my problems are how to return values to the placement_mode method. and how to wait until the result is available

Comment: Have a look at this code snippet https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104333/pyqgis-qgsmaptoolemitpoint

Comment: Yes, that doesn't help, the problem is it seems placement_mode and my custom maptool are run in two different threads. which stops them to wait for each other.I managed to return value by merging both classes into one module and having a global variable which links them. But this is not good programming practice.